# How do I remotely set the timezone and daylight savings time settings of Windows domain computers?

Tags: windows, date-time

How can I *remotely* control/change timezone and Daylight Savings Time (DST) settings of Windows domain computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group policy if you are running Windows Server 2008. See more info here http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/set-a-windows-servers-time-zone-using-group-policy/3673

Or if you are running Windows server 2003 then you have to created a start up script then enable it via group policy. For more info see here http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=2664

Comment: The Windows 2008 method also uses a script, although a simpler one. I was looking for a GPO method only, but thanks anyway.